# How to calculate percentages using QGIS field calculator expression?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

[image: Here is an example of the table I am editing]I am new to QGIS. I am wanting to calculate a field using other fields and some operators.
Here is my expression:

```
case  
When "RVM_CAT" =  'B' OR "RVM_CAT" = 'C' Then ("PC1" /100) * "RE_ha"  
When "RVM_CAT" = 'R' Then ("PC1_1" /100) *  "RE_ha"  
When "RVM_CAT" = 'X' AND "FPC2011"  = 'gr12' Then ("PC1_1" /100) *  "RE_ha"  
ELSE 0  
end
```

When it runs, it looks like it's only calculating values when the PC1_1 value or the PC1 value is 100 if I take out the Else 0, it's the same thing.
There are over 370,000 features
The PC fields are percentages that I need to use to calculate the percentage of the area from the M column. The RVM_CAT column tells me if I use PC1 or PC1_1. So the answer for row 2 uses PC1_1 and is (50/100)*32.03. While the answer for row 3 uses PC1 and is 100/100)*254.73

Comment: Hi, it would be good if you could add samples of what is expected. Just a short table of which values you throw in, what datatype they are, what you expect to happen and what actually happens instead.

Comment: I'm might be wrong but aren't the second and third "WHEN" statement's results exactly the same? What are the other possible values for PC1 and/or PC1_1?

Comment: And don't forget to [use the IN Operator](http://sigsemgrilhetas.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/use-o-operador-in-sff-please-use-the-in-operator/). 

«"RVM_CAT" = 'B' OR "RVM_CAT" = 'C'» is the same as «"RVM_CAT" IN ('B','C')».

Comment: Sounds like you're doing integer division, if it only gives you nonzero values for an input of 100. Try instead to divide by 100.0 or do the multiplication first if you don't care about the decimals.

Comment: I added columns of the table to assist.

Comment: Sorted! lynxlynxlynx was right - i changed the 100 to 100.00 and now it looks like all the values have been calculated